# How to create an activity with two different Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity which I want to access from 2 different activities, I know flags should be used but i do not know how exactly to implement them.
How should I implement Navigation to select proper Activity as Parent?

Comment: "want to access from 2 different activities" -- Okay, you can do that with an Intent. "select proper Activity as Parent" -- You press the back button, and you will go back to the calling Activity. You don't need to "set the parent"

Comment: It is not really necessary to set flags. Just call `finish()` in the child activity then you'll go one step back in the activity back stack.